# Getting onTouch() when user's finger is already on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I dynamically create a View with `onTouchListner`. The problem is it doesn't work when the view is being created the same time the user keeps his finger on the screen. 
To trigger `onTouch()` user has to put his finger off the screen and touch it again.

How to solve that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: I would like to play a sound when the area of newly created View is being touched even when the touch has started right before the view creation.

Comment: Maybe you could get the location of the touch, then check whether the coordinates are within that View when it's created as long as the pointer is still down.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to track coordinates of the touch event when user moves the finger.If the Coordinates are in your views coordinates boundary you can intercept that event and play sound.